# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3 - \cos n}{n^{\frac{2}{3}} - 2}$ divergent, conditionally convergente or absolutely convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was requested  to show whether

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3 - \cos n}{n^{\frac{2}{3}} - 2}$$

converges absolutely, conditionally or diverges. After struggling a bit with finding a way to proceed, I took the following approach and was wondering if it is correct.

$i)$ Because $-1 \leq \cos x  \leq 1$, we know

$$a_n := \frac{3 - \cos n}{n^{\frac{2}{3}} - 2} \geq \frac{3 - (-1)}{n^{\frac{2}{3}} - 2} = \frac{4}{n^{\frac{2}{3}} - 2} \geq \frac{4}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

$ii$) The series $\sum \frac{4}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}$ diverges because $\frac{2}{3} \leq 1$.

$iii)$ A repeated application of the comparison test shows $a_n$ diverges.

I'm pretty new to this and the solution seems too simple to be true, and I'm starting to think I am probably missing something. Is this proof of divergence right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A slight remark on the terminology: it is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ which diverges, *not* $a_n$. You should also have $3-\cos n\geq 3-1=2$, and not what you have right now. It's also a bit unclear by what you mean with "*repeated application* of the comparison test". Other than those remarks, your proof works, well done!

Comment: You are absolutely right on the $3 - 1 = 2$ mistake, and thanks for that terminology correction! By repeated application, I meant that $\sum \frac{2}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}$ diverges and therefore $\sum \frac{2}{n^{\frac{2}{3}} - 2}$ diverges and therefore $\sum a_n$ diverges. It just felt simpler to say "repeated application of the comparison test"

Comment: There's no need to do that as two comparisons. You have shown that $a_n\geq \frac{2}{n^{2/3}}$, and so, as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n^{2/3}}$ diverges, so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.

Comment: I wonder what the divergent sum of this series would be

Answer (score 2):

From the fact that you always have $\cos n\leqslant1$, you can deduce that$$\frac{3-\cos n}{n^{2/3}-2}\geqslant\frac2{n^{2/3}},$$when $n^{2/3}>2$ (that is, when $n>2$). Now, your argument applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly modify the problem to a harder one. Namely $$\sum {1-\cos n\over n^{3/2}-2}\qquad (*)$$
This time we cannot easily apply the comparison test, as $1-\cos n$ is not bounded away from $0.$ Instead we can use the fact that the series $$\sum {\cos n\over n^{3/2}-2}$$ is convergent (conditionally). The series  $$\sum {1\over n^{3/2}-2}$$ is divergent, hence their difference $(*)$ is divergent as well. This approach can be applied to any expression $a-b\cos n$ in the  numerator, but makes use of a nontrivial fact that the series $$\sum a_n\cos n$$ is convergent for $a_n\searrow 0.$